# Displaying Co-authors Plus Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I originally posted this on the Wordpress stack but apparently it was off-topic (???) and it was suggested I ask it here, so here's the original question:

"I'm trying to add the Co-authors Plus plugin to the theme Oldpaper.

However, I've followed the documentation and it simply isn't displaying multiple authors.

As per the instructions [here](http://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/incorporate-co-authors-plus-template-tags-into-your-theme/), the code I've added to single.php:

```
    if ( function_exists
( 'coauthors_posts_links' ) ) {
    coauthors_posts_links();
} else {
    the_author_posts_link();
}
```

However, posts are still displaying only one author. Single.php is the only place where  the_author() is used, so it must be the right place to add the code.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated."

Subsequently, I noticed that the files of the plugin are apparently inactive, according to the Wordpress editor. I'm not sure I believe this because all the backend works, it's just the front end which isn't working.

Comment: It could either be an issue with the function call itself, or an issue with how the plugin is activated. If the function isn't loaded by Wordpress, it won't ever get called. Try adding an `echo "function coauthors_posts_links exists";` inside the `if` statement. Does that print anything out?

Answer (score 0):

If you look further into the instructions...

```
    if ( function_exists( 'coauthors_posts_links' ) ) :
    printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Posted on</span> %2$s <span class="meta-sep">by</span> %3$s', 'twentyten' ),
        'meta-prep meta-prep-author',
        sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><span class="entry-date">%3$s</span></a>',
            get_permalink(),
            esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
            get_the_date()
        ),
        coauthors_posts_links( null, null, null, null, false )
    );
```